# Notify device app for a device-twin update (python)

Tags: python-3.x, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I'm trying to notify my devices for changes in their device-twin. After reading almost all of Azure's documentation, I could not find any solution for notifying the device app for a device twin update directly and not by running a service that subscribers an event-hub, and sends the messages it receives to the device.
Moreover, the python code supplied [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-python-python-c2d) by Azure for sending cloud-to-device messages- crashes.
Does anyone have some successful experience with this kind of communication?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/azure-iot-device/samples/advanced-hub-scenarios/receive_twin_desired_properties_patch.py#L26) you go, from the official github repo.

```
async def twin_patch_listener(device_client):
        while True:
            patch = await device_client.receive_twin_desired_properties_patch()  # blocking call
            print("the data in the desired properties patch was: {}".format(patch))

# Schedule task for twin patch
asyncio.create_task(twin_patch_listener(device_client))
```

Comment: That's nice, but your solution wastes a lot of time for retrieving unchanged desired properties. I would like to have a listener that gets notified when one of the properties changed.

Comment: no, you only get the patch = changed properties. Usually at the beginning you would once retrieve the entire twin. Afterwards only the patches